# Nextjs causing hard refresh when i click in the Link

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an app react using CRA, and I am trying to turn it into an SSR app using next. So, since there is little, the only things I changed were:

- getInitialProps instead of useEffect and useState
- Link from "next / link" instead of using react router dom

But when I click on the link, I get hard refresh.
Here is what is generating the link:

```
<Link href={post.meta.slug}>
    <a>{post.title}</a>
</Link>;
```

I also tried with `href={post.meta.slug} as={post.meta.slug}`.

In my pages directory i have:

- index.jsx
- [slug].jsx

And this is how I get the post in `[slug].jsx`:

```
const PostPage = ({ post }) => {
    return <Base>{post ? <Post post={post} /> : null}</Base>;
};

PostPage.propTypes = {
    post: PropTypes.object,
};

PostPage.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
    const post = await getPostBySlug(query.slug);
    return { post };
};
```

And so far I couldn't identify the error.

Here is the complete code: https://gitlab.com/flakesrc/blog-webstation-next

If you want to clone:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/flakesrc/blog-webstation-next.git
cd blog-webstation-next
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this format for your `Link`?

```
<Link href='/[slug]' as={`/${post.meta.slug}`}>
  <a>{post.title}</a>
</Link>
```

[Here is a good example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/acf7d0ad3bdde5fd579e80325894f4b8a262130f/examples/dynamic-routing/pages/post/%5Bid%5D/index.js) of this type of routing for dynamic pages as well as the section [in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing) that also speaks to this a bit.

Comment: That was the only way it solved, thx. I read the documentation quickly, and use a page translator to read English, so I may have missed something. Can you send me the documentation link where you provide this example?

Comment: @marcossouza this is the documentation link: https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing